# Ignore accessibility settings for Cordova app

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova, cordova-plugins

The answer that is posted everywhere is to use this with the [associated plugin](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-mobile-accessibility):

```
if (window.MobileAccessibility) {
    window.MobileAccessibility.usePreferredTextZoom(false);
}
```

But that doesn't work. The plugin isn't maintained and it has zero effect on the app display in Android 10. I really need to figure out how to ignore the screen zoom setting of the device and display the app normally. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

P.S. please don't leave a comment just to say that this isn't a good idea. I respect your opinion, but I am asking for a solution to my problem, not your thoughts on the problem.

Comment: I would look at various Android View attributes like:[android:importantForAccessibility](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#attr_android:importantForAccessibility) which would be set by the code launching the Cordova framework.